# XCode Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue when I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation

Tags: swift, xcode8, uiimagejpegrepresentation

```
    var data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
```

I am using XCode 8.0 / Swift 3

I sometimes receive a "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" error when i use an image from the UIImagePickerController

I tried to make the compression quality 0.2 instead of 0.8 but the app keeps on crashing.
Anyone knows what's the issue? and how can i solve it?

Comment: what you had done for this? facing similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a memory leak due to some third party library being used in another place. Please check that out and tell me your findings

Comment: Yes I know. The developer must have been an idiot. Using some kind of gif library. he will probably blame a colleague